# tuning GRU network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have a data set collected from an online course, there are about 250 questions and more than 200 students.
dataset contains the following columns

```
studentID, exerciseID, logindate, logoutdate, status, points
```

where `logindate, logoutdate` refer to the date and time of checkin and check out for each record, `status` refer to the progress it vary between 0% and 100% which mean the task is solved if status = 100 and then he gets one `point`.
I want to predict the final exam result according to the previous data.

The student can do each exercise as much as he want, even the task is solved, where each time he access the same exercise only the parameters are vary. for example `ax + b = 0`  then only `a` and `b` are changing in this task, and so I have about 500,000 record, for all students and exercise.

I did some aggregation adding the points in by week, and I tried different ML algorithms, best result I get by applying PCA and only classifying students onto three or four groups (very good, good, satisfactory,failed) but still satisfactory group too chaos ( I can't predict weather be pass or not in the group)

Right now I am trying to do a similar classification deploying a GRU NN as follows.
I take into account the exercises as timestep (250 time steps as results of previous exercise somehow related to the next one), also I did some feature engineering as follows
for each student x, and exercise b, I have

```
 solved, solved_duration, trying, trying_duration, trying_sstatus, check, check_duration
```

where `solved, soved_duraiton` how many times he solved the exercise and how long it takes.
`trying, trying_duration, trying_sstatus` how many times he tried to solve it, how long time it takes and sume of `status 0<status <100`
check, check_duration how many time he check the it without trying to solve it i.e status =0
and then data has the form:

(200,250,7) 200 students (example) 250 exercise (timestep) and 7 features.
So I implemented the following code,

```
n_steps = data.ExerciseID_cat.nunique()

n_features = 8
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(GRU(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(GRU(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax')) # sigmoid

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')  # mse
model.fit(X,y,epochs=1000, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Now my questions are:

1. Do you think this approach is fruitful or not?

   *. if yes how could I tune my code to get a good result, as right now I get now using categorical_crossentropy loss = 0.0000e+00 and never changes,

Note: exam result is categorical (1,2,3,4,5)

*. If not,

2. DO you thing the data are enough to feed it in a NN?
3. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Your final layer has one output, but it needs 5 if you are using softmax so that the result has 5 outputs which sum to 1. Then, these 5 outputs are used roughly as prediction strengths for each category. Categorical/Binary Cross-entropy loss expects predictions and ground truths to be in vector form with one entry per class

Comment: @DerekG thanks for your note about activation function. could you provide me more details or an example of prediction and gound truth  as vectors?

Comment: Well, so, say you had `X[i]`,`y[i]` where the `y[i]`=  5. The correct way to input that label to CCE is `[0,0,0,0,1]`. Then say your model predicts `[1.01,3.04,2.65,2.45,7.65]` (just an arbitrary example). After softmax activation, this becomes `[0.05,0.2,0.15,0.15,0.45]` or something like that (sums to 1). You pass this vector and the ground truth vector to your loss function, which essentially just computes binary cross entropy loss for each possible class. Thus, your model learns not only to predict high confidence for the correct class but also low confidence for all other classes